# How many times has a starting pitcher stuck out all starting hitters?

Tags: baseball, trivia, mlb, pitching

How many times in the history of the MLB, a starting pitcher stuck out all 9 starting hitters of the opposing team at least once in a game?

Answer (score -2):

In the minor leagues it was done once by [Ron Necciai](http://bleacherreport.com/articles/190635-ron-neccai-27-strikeouts-in-nine-inning-game) in 1952, who struck out 27 batters in a game.

Comment: Before answering it's helpful to read [How do I write a good answer?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). and question is asking about MLB so instead of saying it hasn't happened add reference for that also.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question here - it isn't "when were 27 strikeouts made in a game", but instead "when did the starting pitcher strike out every starter for the opposition in one game?". This could be done by striking out the first nine batters, or anywhere across the course of nine innings getting every player once.